# Gate signal problem on my flyback

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver, flyback, gate-driving

Here is my **flyback** converter design.

Vin: 110V
Vout: 24V
Iout: 1A (max)
Desired efficiency: 85%
Transformer ->
P1: 6T
S1: 6T
S2: 5T (aux)
Vro: 24V
EFD30
I determined 15uH for Lp
Ls1: 15uH and Ls2: 8uH
SMPS IC: NCP1252-A (max duty cycle: 48%)
[datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1252-D.PDF)
**Mosfet: STP75NF20** [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stp75nf20.pdf)

[image]

When the transformer is **not connected** at the circuit, **PWM signal** at the mosfet gate is **CLEAR and PROPER**.
But, the transformer is **connected** at the circuit, **gate signal form is being broken**.
[image]
I thougth that the SMPS IC could not be able to generate the gate signal **when directly connected with mosfet**. So, I used a **mosfet driver**. But, the result is the same. Frustration! So, my efficiency remains low **(25%)**

Why is the gate signal being broken?

I measured leakage inductance as 5uH. Does the leakage inductance cause a problem about PWM?

Comment: The gate signal looks OK so, what is your actual problem. I mean you could look at any signal and get too picky about this nuance or that nuance but, is there something actually wrong with your design that makes it not work correctly? What peak current flows through your flyback transformer primary? I estimate 13 amps.

Comment: The IC can source 500mA and sink 800mA on the gate drive, and was characterized with 1nF capacitance (rise and fall times of 28ns and 22ns). You are operating at close to 500kHz, so my guess is that the drive current is insufficient for your application - in this case a discrete driver with higher sink/source capability is the right solution.

Comment: Is the current through the transformer and MOSFET what you think it needs to be? The current should be easy to measure as you have sense resistors.

Comment: The drain voltage and Vsense on the resistors have parasit. So, I changed with 0R and cancelled current sensing. Also, I used external VCC for IC. But, the result is not changed

Comment: Possible scope probing problem - you have to be very careful when probing with high currents. Use a spring clip and a very local ground pin.

Comment: I measured another scope. No problem with scope. The efficiency is very low. I connected a reosta and set 1A output current (24Vx1A). But, input current is 1A (110Vx1A)

Comment: Not the scope itself, but your probe setup. How short is your ground lead?

Comment: My ground probe is too long. But, in my opinion the measurement is true. Because the mosfet gets too hot and the eff. is very low

Comment: You will not see the correct waveform when using a long ground lead.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Miller plateau? I can only suggest to have a look to any MOSFET driving application note.

Comment: Maybe **the miller plateau** is the source of my problem. I will examine the miller plateau and check my circuit. _I will write the result here._

Comment: The MOSFET doesn't seem appropriate for switching it at 500kHz. Did you chose it deliberately for any specific reason?

Comment: I choose this mosfet because of it is **available** in our stock. I **decreased** the frequency to 125 kHz. However, the gate signal is broken. Also, another application  in our devices uses 125 kHz and **same** mosfet. No problem at that app. But,  topology is **different and forward**. I select this frequency (**470 kHz**) in order to use **smaller size** transformer such as **EFD15**. I will change the transformer **in the future**.

Comment: The datasheet you are linking is not the datasheet for the STP75NF20. The screenshot of the data is also from that wrong datasheet. The STP75NF20 appears to be more suited.

Comment: So sorry! I updated the link and removed the SS.

Comment: @carloc `Have you ever heard of Miller plateau? I can only suggest to have a look to any MOSFET driving application note`. I used a mosfer driver (totem pole) and solve this problem. Because, Rsoucre and Rsink resistor values of NCP1252 IC are very high. I calculated max Rgate resistor. It must be 4,88 Ohm max. I decreased power dissipation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any answers about distorted gate drive signals but I'll list down a few mistakes I see:

- For \$\mathrm{P_{OUT} = 24W}\$ and \$\mathrm{f_{SW} = 500kHz}\$, the primary inductance will be much higher than \$\mathrm{15\mu H}\$ even for DCM. Nevertheless, let's see what that \$\mathrm{15\mu H}\$ causes:
- If you force the converter to output 24 Watts then the controller chip will increase the on-time to maintain the required energy which will be stored by the primary inductance *(its magnetic field, actually)* then transferred to secondary (Remember \$\mathrm{V_{IN} = L_p\ i_{ppk}/t_{on}}\$, and \$\mathrm{E_p=0.5\ L_p\ i_{ppk}^2}\$), but the duty cycle is limited to ~%48 by the controller chip, as seen in the oscillogram.
- For \$\mathrm{L_p = 15\mu H}\$ and \$\mathrm{t_{on} = 1\mu s}\$ (i.e. limited duty-cycle), the peak current will be ~7.3A and the RMS current will be 3A. That's why you see ~1A input current at 110VDC input.

So, maybe the distortion is caused by the duty-cycle limitation. Increase the primary inductance to something around \$\mathrm{100-120\mu H}\$ and see what happens.

NOTE: The transformer of a flyback converter **must** have an air gap because most of the energy is stored by the gap itself.

By the way, since you didn't share the full schematic, I'm assuming that the loop is properly closed.

PS: Say hello to Oguz Bey and Selman Bey for me :)

Comment: I will implement your suggestion and write the result here. Aleykum selam :)

Comment: @BunyaminTAMAR From one of your comments above: `Also, another application in our devices uses 125 kHz and same mosfet. No problem at that app. But, topology is different and forward.` Probably it's the 72-to-24 150W railway converter that I designed when I was working there. Now if your aim is to design an alternative converter for railway then **do not ever use flyback topology**. The converter will not pass the railway EMC tests, I assure you.

Comment: **I guess that:** The energy stored in **ton time** is transferred in **toff time**, so the EMC problem occurs. Since there is an **instant** transfer in the forward topology, there is no problem. **Is it true?**

Comment: @BunyaminTAMAR no, not exactly. There are other things, and they are all out of context here. Just take the statement above as a recommendation.

Comment: `Now if your aim is to design an alternative converter for railway then do not ever use flyback topology. The converter will not pass the railway EMC tests, I assure you.`    but still I have to solve this problem

Comment: @BunyaminTAMAR then try the suggestions in my answer. Good luck.